# Trying to find all four letter words in a sentence entered by user and replace them but code won't do anything

Tags: java

Basically I need a code snippet to find all the 4 letter words in a sentence entered by the user and replace them with **** . The code I've written doesn't work no matter how I change it. (It shouldn't count the spaces for example)

```java
public class DisguiseWords {
    static void count(String string) {
        // Create an char array of given String
        int j = string.trim().indexOf(" ");
        while (j > 0) {
            System.out.println(string.substring(0, j) + "-->> words " + j);
            string = string.substring(j + 1).toString();
            j = string.indexOf(" ");
        }
        if (string.length() == 4)
            System.out.println("**** ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Protip if this is for actual filtering of user input (e.g. profanity): users will inevitably find a way to convey what they wanted to convey in the first place. From my experience it's best to provide an (optional) outlet for that, instead of full restriction

Answer (score 1):

`String` has some very handy tools when combined with a regex.

This task can be done like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sentence = "Hello this is the test sentence";
    String newSentence = sentence.replaceAll("\\b\\w{4}\\b", "****");
    System.out.println(newSentence);
}
```

Output:

```
Hello **** is the **** sentence
```

Explanation:

`replaceAll` will take a regular expression and replace each found match with the given replacement. The regex consists of the following parts:

- `\b` marks the word boundary
- `\w{4}` means a word with 4 digits

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use regular expressions, but want to also collect the 4 letter worlds, you can do it like this:

```java
import java.util.*; 
import java.util.stream.*; 

class Playground {
    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
        String sentence = "This is a sentence with some four letter words, like this word.";
        String sentenceWithoutPunctuation = sentence.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "").toLowerCase();
        String[] words = Arrays.stream(sentenceWithoutPunctuation.split(" "))
                               .filter(word -> word.length() == 4)
                               .toArray(String[]::new);

        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
          sentence = sentence.replaceAll(words[i], "****");
        }

        System.out.println(sentence);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just curious but this will probably fail if the dot is after a 4 letter word right? I.e. "This is a sentence with four."

Comment: Yes, it would be better to remove all punctuation mark from the string before extracting the 4 letter words.

Comment: I've updated my answer to take in account punctiation, but at this point @maloomeister answer is the better one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by splitting the String into a String array, then checking whether each item was 4 letters or not like so:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
      String input = scanner.nextLine();
      String[] items = input.split(" ");
      StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
      for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
          if(items[i].length()==4){
              str.append("****");
          }else{
              str.append(items[i]);
          }
          str.append(" ");
          //Appends the space that was rid of during the .split()
      }
      System.out.println(str.toString());
    }
}
```

**Test Run**

*Input*

```
This sentence is sort of interesting
```

*Output*

```
**** sentence is **** of interesting
```

Comment: Would this sentence work:
"Would this sentence work?"
Last word has four letters but there's a punctuation at the end.